# How can I force git submodule update --init to skip errors

Tags: git

I have my folder with active projects I’m working on and all of them are versioned as git submodules. When I set up a new work environment, I clone my folder using `--recursive` (or clone it normally and then do `git submodule update --init --recursive`. Just like link rot, sometimes there’s git remote repo rot (or a server may be down). In these cases I want to init/update only the repos that are available. However, git will stop updating at the first problem it encounters:

```
Cloning into 'dir/name'...
Connection closed by remote.host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'user@example.com:path/to.git' into submodule path 'dir/name' failed
```

and the process stops there.

How can I force git to ignore such errors and just continue to the next submodule?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a flag that will make git ignore such errors, so I wrote a Python script that would achieve (roughly) the same thing. You can put this in the directory of your main project.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def main():
    # The following command may fail
    os.system('cd {} && git submodule update --init --recursive'.format(PROJECT_ROOT))

    # In case the above command failed, also go through all submodules and update them individually
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PROJECT_ROOT):
        for filename in files:
            if filename == '.gitmodules':
                with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as gitmodules_file:
                    for line in gitmodules_file:
                        line = line.replace(' ', '')
                        if 'path=' in line:
                            submodule = line.replace('path=', '')
                            os.system('cd {} && git submodule init {}'.format(root, submodule))
                            os.system('cd {} && git submodule update {}'.format(root, submodule))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/19933161.html) I've found a way to exclude a submodule from `submodule update`. Suppose the module is `dir/name`. Then the recursive update-init command for all submodules except this one will look like

```
git -c submodule.dir/name.update=none submodule update --init --recursive
```

This doesn't automate skipping unforeseen errors, but works fine if you know that some particular submodule won't update.

Comment: This is the answer. Although I got confused by "dir/name" notation.